# How to create multiple child forks and have multiple messages being sent between child processes and main process

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, child-process

I'm trying to create several child forks (using separate worker js file) and have them communicate with my main js file.

I've tried the following:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {  
 worker = childProcess.fork(path.join(__dirname, workerPath));
 workers.push(worker);

 worker.send("variable");

worker.on('message', function(message) {

    worker.send("variable");
        }); 

}
```

This works fine with one worker, however, when I use two workers, it seems the message listener is overwritten when creating the second worker. This results in the first worker stopping and only the second worker continuing. For example if I use the following then the workers work fine:

```
worker1 = childProcess.fork(path.join(__dirname, workerPath));

worker1.send("variable");

worker1.on('message', function(message) {

   worker1.send("variable");
       }); 


worker2 = childProcess.fork(path.join(__dirname, workerPath));

worker2.send("variable");

worker2.on('message', function(message) {

   worker2.send("variable");
       });
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Use different variables for each process? `workers.push(childProcess.fork(...)); workers[i].send("variable");`

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes that's what I tried but I run into an error. In my code you can see that I'm wanting to send a new message when a message is received. However when the program tries to do this I get this error:"Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Comment: It would be good to [edit] your question to include what you've tried, and the errors you've received, so that people don't waste their time suggesting the same...

Comment: @HereticMonkey okay I tried some more and I think I've fixed it. The problem is I was using worker[i].send("variable"); once a message is received. However [i] is undefined because the for loop has ended. So what I did was pass the worker number in the variable 'message' and then I use worker[message].send("variable");. Thanks

Comment: @HereticMonkey sure I tried like 20+ ways with no luck didn't have space to write all of them but sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the key is passing the worker number in the worker 'message' because using workers[i-1].send("variable) gives an undefined error:

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {                  
    workers.push(childProcess.fork(path.join(__dirname, workerPath)));
    workers[i-1].send("variable");

    workers[i-1].on('message', function(message) {

    workers[message-1].send("variable);
       });
```